# Is LIGO measuring an averaged acceleration?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves, ligo

In "Gravitation" by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler the authors pose the following puzzle:

> The metric perturbation of the wave changes the scale of the distances slightly, but also correspondingly changes the scale of time. Therefore does not any possibility of any really meaningful and measurable effect cancel out?

And they also give an answer:

> The widened separation between the geodesics is not a local effect but a cumulative one. [...] When one investigates the separation of geodesics [...] over a large number of periods he finds a cumulative, systematic, net slow bending of the rapidly wiggling geodesics toward each other. This small, attractive acceleration is evidence in gravitation physics [...].

**Is LIGO measuring only a net acceleration (or maybe a net displacement as a cause of the net acceleration)
of the mirrors instead of a wiggling?**
The LIGO collaboration states the opposite. On the FAQ page (https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/faq) you can find

> Back and forth the waves pass through (*interfere with*) each other as the arms themselves change length, causing light interference that ranges fully between totally destructive to totally constructive. In other words, instead of nothing coming out of the interferometer, a flicker of light appears.

**And how could we obtain the frequency of the gravitational wave when averaging over a large number of periods?**

But if I misunderstood the statements in the book "Gravitation", **what is the correct solution of the puzzle stated in the beginning?**

Comment: LIGO is most sensitive at $~200$ Hz. Gravitational waves travel at the speed of light, so the wavelength is much longer than the $4$ km length of the arms.